# I can't build static binary of crystal program under alpine edge

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to compile simplest crystal program, but with `--static` flag:

The code:

```rb
# x.cr
puts "test"
```

Compilation:

```
crystal build --static x.cr
```

The result:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lgc (this usually means you need to install the development package for libgc)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc "${@}" -o '/app/x'  -rdynamic -static  /usr/lib/libpcre.a -lgc /usr/lib/libpthread.a /usr/lib/crystal/core/ext/libcrystal.a /usr/lib/libevent.a /usr/lib/librt.a -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib`
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some `apk` package. I tried `gc`, `gc-dev`, `musl-dev` - no luck - Is it package related, or am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Crystal are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - that was the most important information. I use `alpine:edge` docker image and crystal `0.27.2-r0`.

Comment: Hm, this is really weird. `crystal` on `alpine:edge` depends on `gc-dev` which is obviously missing here. Could you make sure it's correctly installed?

Comment: Yes, I have `gc-dev` installed as well. However I noticed, that most of the packages also have a `*-static` version (i.e. `sqlite-static` etc.). And there is no `gc-static` package in repository - this may be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be that `gc-dev` doesn't provide a static library on `edge` any more. This used to be the case and still is in releases up to `3.9`.

There is a PR to fix that: https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/6970

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for. I downloaded `gc` source, and patch provided by Alpine, and compiled it manually with `--enable-static`.

For people struggling with this, here is an excerpt from my Dockerfile:

`RUN apk add alpine-sdk libatomic_ops-dev linux-headers
WORKDIR /tmp/gc
RUN patch -p1 < /tmp/0001-Fix-gctest-with-musl-libc-on-s390x.patch
ENV CFLAGS "-D_GNU_SOURCE -DNO_GETCONTEXT -DUSE_MMAP -DHAVE_DL_ITERATE_PHDR"
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr --datadir=/usr/share/doc/gc --enable-static --enable-cplusplus && make && make install`

Answer (score 1):

```
apk add crystal shards

# equivalent to build-essentials 
apk add --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc

# or a more complete build dependencies pkg:
# apk add --update alpine-sdk

crystal build --static x.cr
```

I've tested this on a fresh new alpine container.

Comment: Thank you, for your help - I tried that though. The problem is, that I'm using `alpine:edge` image, since I need crystal `0.27.2` (not for this particular code but for bigger project). Using either `virtutal` packages or `alpine-sdk` raises the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing [libgc](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/gc), but this is required by the Crystal package in the repo (if you installed Crystal from there). You might need the [dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/gc-dev) version though, as noted in the [docs](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/All-required-libraries).